# How do I change the color of my ActionBar from the xml.?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of my ActionBar but the color I want to apply doesn't show. Here's my Style.xml file.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#2196f3</item>
</style>

<style name="AboutActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Comment: Check this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744872/actionbar-in-api-8-10-in-android/27745149#27745149)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your activity your extending `Activity` not `ActionBarActivity`

please extend `ActionBarActivity` in your java file like

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{.......}
```

Comment: It does extend ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You also have to set MyTheme to the activity in the AndroidManifest properly.

Like in this thread :
[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Found that AppCompat used colorPrimary to change ActionBar color. Used the following colde and it worked. Hit the Up button if this answer helps you.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196f3</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AboutActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```